# Prismic: How to pull all 'select' fields of a custom type from API?

Tags: reactjs, api, prismic.io

Kinda confused on how to do this, if its even possible?

Lets say I have a custom type called **BLOG**

In that custom type I have a 'Select' options where you can choose the categories (cat 1, cat 2, cat 3)

How can I pull the array of categories into my react app? For example I want to have a list of my categories I can filter my blog posts by, and want to pull them from the same array rather than making a separate array in my app if that makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there isn't a quick and easy way to pull all the available options for a Select field from the API.

In order to do this, it will be a little more complicated, but you have a couple of options.

**1. Query all your Articles**

The first option is to query all your Article documents, then loop through to collect all the Select options that have been selected.

**2. Redo your Select field as Content Relationship**

This is a bit more complicated, but you would first need to setup a new Custom Type for the options of your Select field. Then create a new document for each option. Then you need to update your Select field in your Articles to be a Content Relationship field.

You will need to then go into your documents and select the option you need for each one. It might be a lot of work, but in the end, you'd be able to get all the options available in a single query from the API.

This would work a lot like the custom tagging system described here:

​[Create a Custom Tagging System](https://intercom.help/prismicio/en/articles/2033431-create-a-custom-tagging-system)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I ended up basically going for  #2 here!

Cheers!